# Best layout to display an image right next to text view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to display an image next (on the right) to a text view (single line) using a linear layout with horizontal orientation. I want the image to follow the text immediately. This works well when the text in the text view is small. However for if the text is long the text view takes up the entire width pushing the image outside the container. Tried setting a layout weight to the text view, but this pushes the image to the right end of the container for smaller text. Setting a layout weight to the image, pushes the image outside the layout for large texts.

I also tried different configurations of relative layout. 
1. With the image right_of textview and textview align_parent_start - This also pushes the image outside the layout for long texts. (I don't want to set the image with align_parent_end because that would then push the image to right boundary even for small texts.) 
2. With the textview left_of image and text_view align_parent_start - with this configuration the image seems to overlap with the text.

Is there any way to get this done just using the layout configurations ?

Comment: Checkout layout_weight: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight

Comment: @Gianlu please see my entire question. I have mentioned about my failed attempts with layout_weight.

Comment: Use ConstraintsLayout . I can provide any code sample right now . You can serch for it .

Comment: The only way to make this work, I think, has to be through width setting dynamically. You can measure the widths of the screen and the imageview and set the textview width accordingly

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have an assigned width (not wrap content) for your TextView, for example:

```
  android:layout_width="125dp"
```

If you don't wan't to show the overflowing text use:

```
 android:maxLines="1"
```

If you want to use wrap content you need to use

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:maxWidth="50dp"
```

Comment: Using maxWidth seems to work, but is there a way to compute the maxWidth based on the parent component. something like maxWidth(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT - width_of_image). Because using a plain maxWidth will not work well in my case on different devices and on different orientations (landscape vs portrait).

Comment: Can u test if u put both weights on your image and textview, set android:maxLines="1" and use android:maxWidth="0dp" or android:layout_width="0dp"